# NPM and have package.json file for Prettier

Tags: prettier

I am new to this and trying to install Prettier to keep my VSCode neat. I am following a help file to install prettier and the first thing it says is:

I assume you are using NPM and have package.json file inside the repository. Install Prettier

Can someone help me understand 'NPM and have package.json file inside the repository'?

Answer (score 0):

Which technology stack you are using?
If it is javascript based then in root folder open cmd and type "npm init" this will create package.json automatically.

Comment: I have VSCode. Just installed node-v14.15.4-x64. Then I installed Prettier but it does nothing. I am only trying to code simple HTML. If I code <h1>Heading< /h1> for example, the formatter should correct that gap on closing tag.

Comment: Use ctrl + shift + p for manual formatting. To automate on ctrl + s use below step: open your Visual Studio Code User's settings/preferences as JSON and put in the following configuration:

// Set the default
"editor.formatOnSave": false,
// Enable per-language
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
If you open up the VS Code User's settings/preferences as UI, search for "Format On Save" and make sure to activate it. Afterward, the file should format automatically once you save it

Comment: ctrl + shift + p opens a command pallet and asks me "format document with ...".  I select Prettier but then same thing happens. I have now downloaded more than 10 editors, but nothing works. Honestly, I've been trying for weeks.

Comment: don't worry, I've wasted hours on this .. I wish there was a very simple editor, like notepad or something where I could enter text and format it so it's neat and all the text lines up. Sadly I have to use overly complicated editors to have the formatting feature :(

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of error you are getting, I will try to replicate on my system,